# Можно ли получить список всех участников чата в Telegram?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли каким-то образом получить список всех участников некоторого чата в Telegram? Интересует именно "username" пользователей.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Да, возможно, приложу свой скрипт который справляется с данной задачей, [Github](https://github.com/P-Alban/Telegram-collector)

Также приложу код тут с пояснениями, на случай удаления репозитория:

Делаем необходимые импорты:

```
import sys
from getpass import getpass
from time import sleep
# pip install telethon==0.11.5
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.errors import SessionPasswordNeededError
from telethon.errors.rpc_errors_400 import UsernameNotOccupiedError
from telethon.errors.rpc_errors_420 import FloodWaitError
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import GetParticipantsRequest
from telethon.tl.functions.contacts import ResolveUsernameRequest
from telethon.tl.types import ChannelParticipantsSearch, InputChannel
```

Далее нам нужно создать аккаунт тут https://my.telegram.org и заполнить следующие поля:

```
api_id = 0
api_hash = ''
phone = ''
limit = 100
```

Теперь нам надо авторизоваться:

```
def main():
    # запрашиваем чат
    channel_name = input('Input a channel name, without "@": ')
    client = TelegramClient('current-session', api_id, api_hash)
    client.connect()
    # проверяем не залогинены ли вы уже
    # как можно видеть выше мы создали сессию под именем current-session
    # после первой авторизации можно будет использовать её
    if not client.is_user_authorized():
        try:
            # отсылаем код подтверждения
            client.send_code_request(phone)
            client.sign_in(phone, code=input('Enter code: '))
        # иногда телеграмм блокирует доступ на +- 80к сек
        # так что будьте аккуратны и не посылайте слишком много запросов
        except FloodWaitError as FloodError:
            print('Flood wait: {}.'.format(FloodError))
            sys.exit()
        # проверяем есть ли у пользователя пароль
        # если да, запрашиваем его и логинимся
        except SessionPasswordNeededError:
            client.sign_in(password=getpass('Enter password: '))
    # об этой функции расскажу ниже
    dump_users(get_chat_info(channel_name, client), client)
```

Приступаем к сбору пользователей, для этого нам нужен ID чата и access_hash как [сказано](http://telethon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extra/basic/entities.html?highlight=ResolveUsernameRequest) в документации:

```
def get_chat_info(username, client):
    try:
        chat = client(ResolveUsernameRequest(username))
    except UsernameNotOccupiedError:
        print('Chat/channel not found!')
        sys.exit()
    result = {
        'chat_id': chat.peer.channel_id,
        'access_hash': chat.chats[0].access_hash
    }
    return result
```

Мы получили данные о чате, осталось собрать пользователей:

```
def dump_users(chat, client):
    counter = 0
    offset = 0
    # нам нужно сделать объект чата, как сказано в документации 
    chat_object = InputChannel(chat['chat_id'], chat['access_hash'])
    all_participants = []
    while True:
        # тут мы получаем пользователей
        # всех сразу мы получить не можем для этого нам и нужен offset 
        participants = client.invoke(GetParticipantsRequest(
                    chat_object, ChannelParticipantsSearch(''), offset, limit
                ))
        # если пользователей не осталось, т.е мы собрали всех, выходим
        if not participants.users:
            break
        all_participants.extend(['{} {}'.format(x.id, x.username)
                           for x in participants.users])
        users_count = len(participants.users)
        # увеличиваем offset на то кол-во юзеров которое мы собрали
        offset += users_count
        counter += users_count
        print('{} users collected'.format(counter))
        # не забываем делать задержку во избежания блокировки
        sleep(2)
    # сохраняем в файл
    with open('users.txt', 'w') as file:
        file.write('\n'.join(map(str, all_participants)))
```

Получаем уютный текстовик в формате:

```
ID USERNAME
```

Использовалось [Telegram Client API](https://core.telegram.org/methods), в качестве обёртки [telethon](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon)

Answer (score 1):

Одной командой вроде `get.ChatMembers` нельзя, но можно воспользоваться обходными путями, например, если вам нужен список всех участников чата, например вручную забить в базу данных их никнеймы, а лучше их `id`, так как никнейм, в отличии от `id` может поменятся. Можно создать новый чат и при вступлении в него пользователя регистрировать его с помощью метода `new_chat_members`. Ну или можно создать штучную регистрацию, чтобы участники отправили какое-то сообщение вроде `/reg` и бот автоматически добавил их в бд.

Answer (score 0):

Код, представленный Pavel Durmanov, работает, но для российского IP нужно использовать proxy:

```
proxy = (socks.SOCKS5, "HOST", PORT)
client = TelegramClient('current-session', api_id, api_hash, proxy)
```