# Пару вопросов по pyTelegramApi (telebot)

Tags: python, база-данных, telegram, telebot

У меня есть два вопроса которые я не знаю как реализовать.
Первый вопрос - я добавил своего бота в чат, как получить список участников (через какой метод, если такой имеется).
Второй вопрос как после отправки сообщения боту, он разрешал нажимать на ту же самую кнопку уже на следующий день, то-есть кнопка работает один раз в день для всех участников.
Вот макет кода:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def ohh(message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    if message.text == ' Кликуха дня?' or message.text.lower() == 'кликуха дня' or message.text.lower() == 'кликуха':
    time.sleep(1)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '` Подключаем базу ...`',parse_mode='Markdown')
    time.sleep(3)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '`Ваня лашпед ...`',parse_mode='Markdown')
```

Comment: Первый вопрос:
Я тоже хотел сделать такое у своего бота, долго искал и в результате ничего не нашёл. Челы со стаковерфлоу сказали, что такой функции пока нету, и надо разве делать базу данных участников каждого чата, куда их записывать, когда бот видит какое-то сообщение.
Второе:
Я вообще не очень разбираюсь, но думаю тут надо в ту же базу данных записывать, когда в последний раз человек нажимал на кнопку, и если меньше дня назад, то она ничего не будет делать

Comment: понял, но как задать чтобы после 12:00 ночи эта кнопка срабатывала?

Comment: Можно запоминать день, когда пользователь пользовался, и если сейчас другой день, то уже прзволять

Comment: на счёт первого вопроса - https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getchatmember

Comment: это не совсем то, потому что я получу информацию только о том человеке, который взаимодействует с моим ботом, а мне нужно чтобы бот получил весь список участников

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/783686/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%85-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-telegram