# Как сделать рассылку по участникам группы в Телеграмм?

Tags: api, telegram

Канал в Телеграмм не мой.
Но мне нужно осуществить рассылку по всем его участникам помогите

Comment: Прочитай об это вот здесь, возможно поможет https://zen.yandex.ru/media/igorzuevich/3-soveta-kak-sdelat-rassylku-v-telegram-5e6e161353be0d0a19b23ed3?utm_source=serp

Answer (score 1):

### Никак

Участников **канала** может видеть только его администратор.

Comment: Более того, даже администратор не может увидеть весь список участников полностью. Только 200. Хотя в теории, можно мониторить в недавних действиях новых и покинувших участников, таким образом накапливая список со своей стороны. Недавние действия видны только за последние два дня.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего вам поможет [Telethon](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon). Можно использовать эту библиотеку для симуляции действий в Telegram пользователя без GUI. Вам понадобится аккаунт Telegram, желательно не основной. Таким образом вы можете автоматизировать рассылку. Примерный алгоритм:

Авторизация. Определение участников канала. Рассылка сообщений.

Вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/783686/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%85-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-telegram) первые шаги описаны.

А вообще ваша задача тянет на спам, а это очень плохо!

Comment: Никакого спама!